# Optimizing a query in Laravel by model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have four tables named `practice`, `section`, `book`, and `grade`.
The flow is that each practice is related to a section of the patch one book, each section to a patch book, and each book to a level of study.

For example, the practice of solving the **Venn diagram** is part of the **first chapter** of the **ninth** grade **math** book.

I want to have a query that has the practice that are related to a specific grade.

I ran this query on Laravel myself:

```
$grade = 9;  //Example
$practice = DB::table('practices')
    ->select('practices.id')
    ->where('teacher_id', $teacher->id)
    ->where('code', $practiceCode)
    ->join('sections', 'practices.section_id', '=', 'sections.id')
    ->join('books', 'sections.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
    ->where('books.grade_id', $grade)
    ->first();
```

But I don't get an object with this query and I have to convert it to an object when I want to send it to the blade view. This is how I did it:

```
$practice_id = $practice->id ;
$practiceObject = Practice::find($practice_id);
```

But I want to implement this query using the model if possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have correctly set the relationships, why aren't you using the relationships? Why are you using joins and that when you have relationships? Did you try using `with` to eager load?

Comment: Look at the [Laravel Eloquent documentation for retrieving models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-models). On the model you can use `Practice::where` etc.. as seen in the docs. You can get the related records using [Laravel Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

First of all set the relations in the models
And then I would try to build something using the 'with' and/or 'whereHas' methods like this:

```
$practice = Practices::where([
  'teacher_id', $teacher->id,
  'code', $practiceCode
 ])
 ->whereHas('sections', function ($query) {
   $query->where('practice_id ...')
 })
 ->with('relations_you_want'...)
 ->first()
```

If you don't know how to do it, take a look [here in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships)

Hope that help you!